# Carregar registros de diferentes tabelas como anonymous type entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework

Como posso carregar os dados de múltiplas tabela no Entity Framework? Pela `RAW Query` eu consigo normal, mas pelo Entity Framework não estou conseguindo chegar ao ponto.

O que preciso é selecionar a última entrada que contenha um produto especifico (vou passar a ID) ordenado pela DataCadastro decrescente (identificar que é a ultima) e junto selecionar o objeto do PRODUTO que eu passei a ID?

**Obs:** *Removi as annotations e mapeamento para diminuir o tamanho do post!*

Eu acesso a entrada através do meu:

```
contexto.Entrada.Lista().Where(...).OrderByDescending(m => m.DataCadastro).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Classes:**

```
class Entrada {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }      
    public virtual ICollection<ItemEntrada> Items;
}    
class Produto {
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}    
class ItemEntrada {
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public int EntradaId { get; set; }      
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }      
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; };       
    public virtual Entrada Entrada { get; set; };
}
```

Comment: Coloque Apolo a sua SQL que você colocou na sua `RAW`?

Comment: Fiz com join mas não posso usar RAW SQL preciso utilizar entity framework no projeto.

Comment: Apolo, quero ver sua Raw SQL que ai eu tiro e mando pelo Entity entendeu!

Comment: Maria agradeço a ajuda, mas contém informações da empresa e processo, não posso passar! Os dados acima são inventados! No caso da query ele me retornaria a entrada e o produto como um Anonymous Type!

Comment: Ok @Apolo, eu fiz uma resposta vamos ver se da certo... !!! por favor teste e me fale! Se eu ver a SQL eu gero qualquer `Lambda Expression` seria mais tranquilo ... mas, tudo bem vamos respeitar a empresa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como relatado pelo OP da pergunta, fiz uma simulação pelos dados fictícios...

```
int Id = 1; // id do produto;
var resultado = contexto.ItemEntrada
        .Include("Produto")
        .Include("Entrada")
        .Where(x=>x.Produto.Id == Id)
        .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Entrada.DataCadastro)
        .Take(1)
        .Select( x => new {
            EntradaId = x.EntradaId,
            DataCadastro = x.Entrada.Datacadastro,  
            ProdutoId = x.Produto.Id, 
            ProdutoNome = x.Produto.Nome
        });
```

Comment: A Entrada não possui reference ao Produto. A entrada contém vários itens que esses contém 1 produto cada! Vlw pela ajuda!

Comment: Eu to arrumando @Apolo! agora que eu vi!

Comment: @Apolo da uma olhada! agora porque se tem que pegar pelo `ItemEntrada`

Comment: You are FODA Maria! Vlw mesmo deu certo. Eu não preciso do Include("Produto") e Include("Entrada") a menos que eu queira um Eager Loading certo?

Comment: Certo @Apolo, é como eu não sei da sua configuração do Entity já coloquei de cara e forcei isso como padrão...! mas, que bom que foi solucionado...! Olha só uma dica uma boa pratica é desabilitar esse carregamento para que sua aplicação ganhe velocidade e você force (por include) o carregamento quando o precisar, de vez em quando não precisamos ... kkkk mas, que bom que foi solucionado.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica!